# Use class by calling random name

Tags: python, class, random

I get error printing `result.age`, why? How I can fix it?

```
import random

names = ['Bob', 'Robert', 'Tom']
result = random.choices(names, weights=[5, 10, 12], k=random.randint(1, 3))
print(result)

class People:
    def __init__(self, age, city):
        self.age = age
        self.city = city

Bob = People('23', 'NewYork')
Robert = People('73', 'Boston')
Tom = People('43', 'Oslo')

print(result.age)
```

Comment: Because `result` is a string and strings don't have an `age` attribute, although instances of your `class` *do* (hint).

Comment: @martineau That should be posted as an answer rather than as a comment. Comments are temporary and cannot be accepted as an answer. There is no mechanism for converting comments to answers, so I cannot do it for you. You will need to copy your comment into the answer box and then delete your comment.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen, but I am very familiar with how things work around here and would have posted it as an answer if I had wanted to do so. My intent was to make the OP determine the answer for themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Because `result` is not one of your objects.  It's just a string.  You can do it like this.  Note that I made a list of objects, not a list of strings.

```
import random

class People:
    def __init__(self, age, city):
        self.age = age
        self.city = city

Bob = People('23', 'NewYork')
Robert = People('73', 'Boston')
Tom = People('43', 'Oslo')

names = [Bob, Robert, Tom]
result = random.choices(names, weights=[5, 10, 12], k=random.randint(1, 3))
print(result)
print(result.age)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but still can't run it. It show me now that the result.age is a list and dont have attribute age.

Comment: @Agora99 that is a minor issue, this pretty much answers your question...

Answer (score 1):

First, your list `name` only contains strings, not the objects (`Bob`, `Robert`, and `Tom`) you created. So use `[Bob, Robert, Tim]` instead (note a lack of quotes).

Second, the result would be a list (with varying length), not a single object chosen from the pool. To print the age of the items in the list, you would need to use some form of loop; `for`, list comprehension, or the like.

```py
import random

class People:
    def __init__(self, age, city):
        self.age = age
        self.city = city

Bob = People('23', 'NewYork')
Robert = People('73', 'Boston')
Tom = People('43', 'Oslo')

friends = [Bob, Robert, Tom]
result = random.choices(friends, weights=[5, 10, 12], k=random.randint(1, 3))

output = [p.age for p in result]
print(output) # ['73', '73', '23']; The outpupt may vary from time to time.
```